# How to read file from host network in windows docker container

Tags: docker, spring-boot

I have create spring boot application, where i can read the file from the network shared location(Using rest API - Simple just read the file). I able able to read the file, if i run the application in to the my machine. But while run same application from the windows docker container it is giving exception "java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\domain name\TestFolder\readme.txt (No such file or directory)"

**Docker Details**

Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

Is there any way to read the file from host network within Docker container?

Thanks 
Dhaval

Comment: What user context is the code running in inside the container? Does that user have permissions to that file share?

Comment: Mount a volume to share this file if it is not inside the container